# SQL-запрос из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Дано:
t1, t2 - таблицы заказов и юзеров соответсвтенно
в t1 поля id, user, date
в t2 поля id и email

Задача:
Написать SQL-запрос на выборку t1.id и t2.email тех юзеров, чьи заказы были сделаны раньше, чем 3 дня назад.

Накопал вот что:

```
SELECT user FROM t1 WHERE date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Осталось сделать выборку из t2 (WHERE id = t1.user)
Я могу это сделать на php, но мне необходимо это в одном запросе.

Comment: Почитайте по join.

Comment: @Чад, благодарю, разобрался. RIGHT OUTER JOIN решает проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете извлечь пользователей, кто заказаывал ранее чем три дня назад

```
SELECT
  users.email AS email
FROM
  t2 AS users
LEFT JOIN
  t1 AS orders
ON
  users.id = orders.user
WHERE
  orders.date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND
  orders.id IS NOT NULL
```

Однако, этот запрос не извлекает заказы, если вы попробуете добавить в конструкцию SELECT orders.id, то в MySQL будет извлечен любой случайный идентификатор заказов (если у пользователя их несколько).

Если вы воспользуетесь просто JOIN-объединением, вы сможете извлечь все заказы, сделанные ранее трех дней. Однако, пользователи users.email будут повторяться, то количество раз, сколько пользователь сделал заказ.

```
SELECT
  orders.id AS order_id,
  users.email AS email
FROM
  t2 AS users
JOIN
  t1 AS orders
ON
  users.id = orders.user
WHERE
  orders.date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Как вариант, можно воспользоваться, первым запросом LEFT JOIN, извлекая список идентификаторов заказов при помощи функции GROUP_CONCAT()

```
SELECT
  users.email AS email,
  GROUP_CONCAT(orders.id) AS orders_ids
FROM
  t2 AS users
LEFT JOIN
  t1 AS orders
ON
  users.id = orders.user
WHERE
  orders.date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND
  orders.id IS NOT NULL
```